# speed up the processing of excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

I've created excel vba file. However, it takes very long time to run the whole file because the total of the rows is up to 270,000 lines. Does anyone know how can I speed up the running process? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
Sub datemodifiedFile()
Dim File1 As Object
Dim fso As Object
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set File1 = fso.getfile("C:\Users\Meg\Desktop\Master File.xlsx")
If Sheets("today").Range("B1").Value = File1.DateLastModified Then
Else
Sheets("today").Range("B1").Value = File1.DateLastModified
Dim WbB As Workbook
Set WbB = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\Users\Meg\Desktop\Master File.xlsx", ReadOnly:=True)
Dim SheetB As Worksheet
Dim lastrow As Long
Set SheetB = WbB.Sheets("Sheet1")
        SheetB.Select
        Rows("1:1").Select
        'Selection.AutoFilter
        'ActiveSheet.Range("A:V").AutoFilter Field:=20, Criteria1:=""
        Columns("A:V").Select
        Selection.Copy
        ThisWorkbook.Activate
        Sheets("today").Select
        Range("C1").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
               :=False, Transpose:=False
        'Columns("A:X").Select
        'ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$X$750001").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(3, 4, 6), _
        Header:=xlYes
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        lastrow = Sheets("today").Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Sheets("today").Cells(lastrow, 3).EntireRow.Delete
WbB.Close False
End If
End Sub
Sub dltnew()
        Dim i As Long
        Dim lrow As Long
        lrow = Sheets("today").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 2 To lrow
        If Sheets("today").Cells(i, 2).Value = "NEW" Then
        Sheets("today").Cells(i, 2).Value = ""
        Sheets("today").Cells(i, 1).Value = ""
End If
Next i
End Sub
Sub comdate()
Dim Sheet1 As Worksheet
Dim Sheet3 As Worksheet
Dim lrow As Long
Dim i As Long
Set Sheet1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("main")
Set Sheet3 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("today")
Sheet3.Range("A1").Value = Date
Sheet3.Range("A1").NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
Sheet3.Range("A1").Font.Color = Sheet3.Range("A1").Interior.Color
Sheet3.Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
If Sheet1.Range("B1").Value <> Sheet3.Range("A1").Value Then
   Sheet1.Range("B1").Value = Sheet3.Range("A1").Value
    lrow = Sheet1.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To lrow
    If Sheet1.Cells(i, 2).Value = "NEW" Then
    Sheet1.Cells(i, 2).Value = ""
    End If
    Next i
    End If
End Sub
Sub Con()
Dim LasRow As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
LasRow = Sheets("today").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Sheets("today").Range("A2:A" & LasRow).Formula = "=C2&G2&I2"
ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
Sub Compare()
    Dim mrow As Range, trow As Long
    With Worksheets("main")
        Set mrow = .Range("A2", .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    End With
    trow = Worksheets("today").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    With Worksheets("today")
        For j = 2 To trow
            If mrow.Find(What:=.Range("A" & j).Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole) Is Nothing _
             Then .Range("B" & j).Value = "NEW"
        Next j
    End With
End Sub
Sub getnew()
Dim Sheet1 As Worksheet
Dim Sheet3 As Worksheet
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim erow As Long
Set Sheet1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("main")
Set Sheet3 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("today")
lastrow = Sheet3.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To lastrow
    If Sheet3.Cells(i, 2).Value = "NEW" Then
    erow = Sheet1.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Sheet3.Cells(i, 2).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheet1.Range("A" & erow)
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Sheet1.Select
    Range("A1:X750001").Select
    Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("G2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Key2:=Range("C2") _
        , Order2:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:= _
        False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
End If
Next i
End Sub
Sub hidecellvalue()
Dim Sheet1 As Worksheet
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim k As Long
Set Sheet1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("main")
lastrow = Sheet1.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For k = 2 To lastrow
If Sheet1.Cells(k, 1).Value <> "NEW" Then
Sheet1.Cells(k, 1).Font.Color = Sheet1.Cells(k, 1).Interior.Color
'Sheet1.Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
End If
Next k
End Sub
Sub hideSh1column()
Dim Sheet1 As Worksheet
Set Sheet1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("main")
Sheet1.Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Sheet1.Columns("D:F").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Sheet1.Columns("H:H").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Sheet1.Columns("L:L").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Sheet1.Columns("N:N").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Sheet1.Columns("P:P").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
End Sub
Sub HideSheet3()
Sheets("today").Visible = xlSheetVisible
End Sub
```

Comment: Which part takes the most time?  You can use `Debug.Print` and `Timer` to output how long each part takes.  That's too much code so it would help to focus down on the problem areas.

Comment: It's possible that this code dump would be better suited as a [performance] question at [Code Review - Excel](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/excel). Read their [What topics can I ask about here?](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and consider migrating the question over if you feel it is a good fit.

Comment: Hi Tim Williams. Thank you for your suggestion and I found that the Sub Compare() takes the longest time to run. It runs endlessly without showing any time.

Comment: Hi Jeeped. Thaks for your suggestion. I was wondering how can I move to Code Review - Excel as I'm new to here.

Comment: If you click [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35594227/edit) you can copy this question's source to Notepad in prep to creating another question on Code Review. This question can then be [delete](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35594227)d. When you post on Code Review, add some narrative about what this code actually accomplishes. Adding a link to some sample data would be appreciated; it's tiresome to have to reproduce data that may not even be accurate for testing purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with remove as much as `.activate` and `select` you have in your code and replace it with proper sheet.cell/range selection. 
Then i would add this on beggining of your code

```
Dim previousScreenUpdating As Boolean
previousScreenUpdating = Application.ScreenUpdating
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim previousCalculation As XlCalculation
previousCalculation = Application.Calculation
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
```

and this on the end of your code

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = previousScreenUpdating
Application.Calculation = previousCalculation
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be much faster.

You should always try to do as much using arrays as possible, rather than going through your data cell-by-cell.

In addition, a dictionary-based lookup is always going to beat using Find() when you're checking things in a large loop.

```
Sub Compare()

    Dim mrow As Range, trow As Long, arr, r As Long
    Dim d As Object, rngV As Range
    Dim arrV, arrN, wsT As Worksheet, wsM As Worksheet

    Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Set wsM = Worksheets("Main")
    Set wsT = Worksheets("today")

    'get all unique values in ColA on Main
    arr = wsM.Range(wsM.Range("A2"), wsM.Cells(wsM.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Value
    For r = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
        d(arr(r, 1)) = 1
    Next r

    Set rngV = wsT.Range(wsT.Range("A2"), wsT.Cells(wsT.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
    arrV = rngV.Value                 'values from colA as array
    arrN = rngV.Offset(0, 1).Value    'values from colB as array

    'check colA against the dictionary and update colB array as needed
    For r = 1 To UBound(arrV, 1)
        If Not d.exists(arrV(r, 1)) Then arrN(r, 1) = "NEW"
    Next r
    'repopulate ColB with updated data
    rngV.Offset(0, 1).Value = arrN

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Tim Williams. This is indeed a lot faster. I was wondering how can I modify the code and speed up the running of Sub getnew() as well for the circumstances that they are too many new information being updated in one time?

Comment: Why are you resorting the sheet every time you copy a "NEW" row -   surely you only need to do that once after you're done copying?  And Luboš has good suggestions for improving your general speed of execution.

Comment: Hi Tim Williams. This is because I have data which is classified in different categories and "NEW" row might be added in the middle of the sheet, not the last row all the time. Therefore, everytime when it is being copied over to another sheet, it needs to be resorted to match its category. For instance, if broccoli is "NEW", then it will be added to vegetable category whereas if is orange, it will be added to fruit category.

Comment: I can see why you might need to sort, but not why sorting multiple times gives you a different outcome from running a single sort when you're done with the loop.  A single sort will still group everything by category.

Comment: Hi Tim Williams. I got what you meant. Thank you very much. Between, I was wondering whether is there any other faster way for the loop? The "NEW" might be reside in row 5, 7, 10, 25, 100 in Sheets("main"). I was thinking whether can I collect all the "NEW" rows altogether and copy at the bottom of the page in Sheets("today") then sort them out and that will be faster?

Comment: Hi Tim Williams. Do you reckon that if I filter "NEW" in Sheets("main") and copy paste to Sheets("today") and sort it all that will be faster than i use looping?

Comment: Yes a filter might be faster.  Try it out